# Is there a consistent hashing algorithm that support zero remapping of keys?

Tags: algorithm, hash, cluster-computing, consistent-hashing

I understand with the classical consistent caching algorithm, when adding/removing a node, some keys have to be remapped to different nodes. Is there an algorithm that supports no remapping at all, if I loosen some requirements?

In my application, I want to incrementally assign keys to nodes:

1. Once a key has been assigned to a node, it stays there forever.
2. Nodes are added but not removed. a node is never down after being added - assume a replication/backup mechanism at work.
3. Keys don't need to be distributed uniformly among the nodes. Best-effort is OK: when a new node is added, more new keys are assigned to it than the old nodes.

   Is there an algorithm for this scenario?

Comment: What you ask for cannot be achieved in a stateless manner. Say, such algorithm would need to know average load on the rest of the nodes to manage when to go or not to go to a new node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can image two similar workarounds that could give you what you’re asking for, but both come with conditions that probably are not acceptable:

1. If cache clients know in what sequence keys were first requested, i.e. if cache keys include a monotonically increasing id or version number of some kind, then you could keep track of the sequence numbers at which the cluster size increased, and compute the hash according to the number of nodes that existed at that time.
2. If you don’t mind a two-stage lookup, you could keep a key → numnodes lookup table that records how many nodes there were at the time a key was cached, then use that to compute the hash code. Or just keep a key → cachenode lookup table.

(A variation on #2 if the two-stage lookup is OK, but size of the lookup table is a concern: keep a hash(key) → cachenode lookup table, and make that hash as small as you need it to be to keep the lookup table small. If two keys happen to have the same hash, they end up on the same node — but that’s not a concern if the balancing isn’t strict.)

Neither of these techniques even relies on consistent hashing — just naive hash codes — but both are quite limiting.

In the general case, without something that ties a key to information about the state of the cache at the time that key was first cached, then no, I don’t think what you’re asking for is possible.

Comment: Your first workaround is exactly what I was thinking about, but the monotonically increasing key seems quite restrictive.

Comment: I think the “variation on #2” is promising, if you can tolerate the two-stage lookup and that first lookup being such a hot spot. No matter how you do it, you’ll have to figure out some way to encode some part of the past in the present.

Comment: Yeah, I will try that. Thanks!